# Making a copy of a spreadhseet through apps script that copies from another Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking to run a script from a button that will copy a Spreadsheet that is located in another users Google Drive.

I have created the below script but this comes up with an error `Exception: Access denied: DriveApp.`

```
   var tracker = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheet_id');
   var template = DriveApp.getFileById('sheet_id');

   var folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();

   var getFilename = ui.prompt('Copy Sheet', 'Please enter a filename for your Money Tracker:', ui.ButtonSet.OK)
   var filename = getFilename.getResponseText();

   var newFile = template.makeCopy(filename, folder);

   var url = newFile.getUrl();

   tracker.getSheetByName('Copies').appendRow([coppyer,email,accNo,Access,filename, url]);
```

Has anyone got an idea of what I need to do to this so that it copies the sheet please?

Comment: if you don't have permission to copy the item you can't copy the item

Comment: Do you have at least view permission on the target Spreadsheet? Or is it a public Spreadsheet?

Comment: @Andres - yes, the target spreadsheet does have view permission on it

Comment: On the file for this line `var template = DriveApp.getFileById('sheet_id');` do you have permissions? I'm using your code with edit permissions for the file in this line: ` var tracker = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheet_id');` (otherwise you can't use menu buttons) and with view permissions for the Drive file, and it's working as intended without error.

Comment: @Andres, is your test scenario with a sheet in a different users Google drive?

Comment: Yes. Are you using G Suite? You might have Drive API access disabled for your users in admin console, read about [access denied error](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#access_denied_driveapp_or_the_domain_policy_has_disabled_third-party_drive_apps)